# DNS A record + .htaccess confusion

Tags: .htaccess, dns

I'm setting up a website with Digital Ocean. I want to have the `home` subdomain of my website handled by my webserver at home, and everything else handled by my Digital Ocean webserver.

So I added an A record pointing `home.mywebsite.com` to my home network's IP address. This works fine. But since updating the .htaccess file on my Digital Ocean webserver (in the /var/www/html directory), I've noticed that it is interfering with things on `home.mywebsite.com`. I have a Java application running on my home computer that loads classes from `home.mywebsite.com/classes/` (with `URLClassLoader`) but it gets a `ClassNotFoundException` whenever the .htaccess file is on my Digital Ocean webserver.

Maybe I don't understand how DNS resolution works exactly, but I assumed that when I add an A record, the request will be forwarded before it is handled by my Digital Ocean webserver? So why would .htaccess even be effecting anything on my home webserver?

The .htaccess that is causing problems simply forwards a different subdomain (`example`) to `mywebsite.com/example`.

This is my .htaccess file on my Digital Ocean webserver:

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.mywebsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/example
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ example/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Can you open (in browser) 'home.mywebsite.com/classes/' from within your home network?